# gtk-launch only works when present working directory is Desktop

Tags: desktop-environment, gtk, .desktop

I just figured out how to manually create a `.desktop` file which allows a program to be launched by issuing the command `gtk-launch` [program.desktop]. Problem is it only seems to work if my present working directory is the Desktop directory for my username. Thus when I enter the command `gtk-launch program.desktop` it runs.

The problem is when I try to enter `gtk-launch /home/userName/Desktop/program.desktop`. Instead I get a message from terminal saying: **gtk-launch: no such application.** I know the file is there and cat works just fine reading it.

Why does gtk-launch only seem to be working from inside Desktop? Can I get around this? I'm using Kali linux with GNOME from a persistent USB.

Comment: Did you find any of what was posted useful? It is always good to provide feedback.

Comment: To clarify for future visitors, this was an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where _X_ was "use `gtk-launch` to launch a program" and _Y_ was "get `gtk-launch` to understand absolute filesystem paths" —which, as noted below, it doesn't. I can totally relate to this, because my _X_ and _Y_ were the same. `;)`

Answer (score 7):

To make this work, you have to satisfy two requirements:

1. Your `myapp.desktop` file should reside in one of several directories (not exclusively `/usr/share/application`). These depend on your Linux distro; for Ubuntu:

   1.1. `/usr/share/application`

   1.2. `/usr/local/share/applications`

   1.3. `~/.local/share/applications`
2. You have to execute `gtk-launch myapp` (or `gtk-launch myapp.desktop`) **without** the path.

Related:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/471282/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-desktop-file-from-a-quicklist

https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal

Answer (score 2):

The manpage states the following:

> gtk-launch takes at least one argument, the name of the application to
>   launch. The name should match application desktop file name, as
>   residing in /usr/share/application, with or without the '.desktop'
>   suffix.

This indicates that the desktop file should be in the specified location, otherwise it can't used to launch an application. Source file [gtk/gtk-launch.c](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/4724a89022ef1bec93b1a42d4cf2fec7191ed712/gtk/gtk-launch.c) shows that gtk-launch doesn't execute anything, but puts a message on D-Bus to to ask for the launch the required application.

Comment: Ah yes. It does. Although it does beg the question--how does one launch a program via a .desktop file with the command line from OUTSIDE of the desktop? I haven't come across any solution which does not involve gtk-launch.

Comment: For that [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal) on AskUbuntu may set you on your way.